# Connect the keyboard and mouse reciever into a bluetooth dongle

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, adapter, wireless-keyboard, dongle

I have a use-case i'd really like to know if is possible to achieve or not.

I have a keyboard and mouse that comes with a usb-stick, it connects to my laptop, or any other device supporting it, and i am good to go. But is it possible, to connect my phone to some sort of Bluetooth adapter that would take this usb stick, and then operate the mouse from that?

Just like we used to do on a wired to wireless headphone converter, something of this sort [https://www.amazon.com/Original-Xiaomi-Bluetooth-Receiver-Headphone/dp/B074S3KCRM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074S3KCRM)

Please let me know if i am not able to explain my scenario.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such product exist,
[Example 1](https://aliexpress.com/item/4000102207746.html)
[Example 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0823V6MXX)
[Example 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V4STT3T)

But to be honest, these products probably will not work reliably because USB and Bluetooth are completely different kind of protocol/standard. Trying to convert one protocol to another is risky (in term of reliability). Since they have not been designed to work together since the beginning.

The best solution would be, to get a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard